# No wireless access from Ubuntu, but do get wireles access with XP on the same machine

Tags: wireless, ralink, ndiswrapper

Got a desktop with XP and Ubuntu.
New to linux, have some knowledge of vi and unix.
The XP wireless works, Ubuntu wireless does not, get - hardblocked:yes.
Its an old Medion desktop, motherboard MS-7091, the wireless is on an internal USB.

(Its got a wired link thats never worked, and never investigated that as did okay with XP and wireless.)

Investigating 3 possible ways around the wireless block :-
1. unblocking the hard block.
2. updating the linux wireless driver - `rt2500usb` via the command line
3. Replacing the linux wireless driver with windows driver using `ndiswrapper`

Was trying to get `ndiswrapper` through the GUI off the installation disk but after double clicking ndiswrapper the install option was disabled,
So looking at command line install of `ndiswrapper`.
Not so hot on using linux and `ndiswrapper`, tar, installing drivers etc...
so any help will be appreciated

Comment: try to avoid ndiswrapper... please add to your question the version of ubuntu you are using, together with the result of `sudo lshw -class network` and `rfkill list all`.  Thanks.  Remember, a "hard-block" means its  a hardware issue that cannot be resolved by software.

Answer (score 0):

Try this link, they may have the solution

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1739425&page=2